# C++ Recursive Function that calls itself N Times?

Tags: c++, function, boost, recursion

suppose I have a function:

```
int recursive(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int NbPositions)
{ //the following is a recursive function that will call itself 3 times
 //code to be repeated goes here
 recursive(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int NbPositions);
}
```

what I can't figure out is how to be able to let the function know WHICH recursion number it's on, and how to stop it. Any efficient and clever way to do this? If it helps I'm using the boost algorithm.

Comment: Most immediate: pass it as an argument.. do you have any signature constraints?

Comment: Normally a recursive call has some criteria for not recursing. In this case, if it truly is a specific count and no other criteria, you could pass the count as an argument (as @MarcoA indicated) and decrement it on each call. When you see it go to zero, that's when you don't recurse.

Answer (score 5):

Pass it a parameter and check it before executing the function.If the iteration is over, return the result, otherwise continue

```
int recursive(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int NbPositions,int repeat)
{ 
 repeat --;
   if(repeat==0)
 return result;
   else
 recursive(NbProducts, NbPlates, NbPositions, repeat);
}
```

If you want it to repeat 3 times, you just have to say

```
recursive(NbProducts, NbPlates, NbPositions, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

*(WARNING: This will only work if you don't have any function signature constraints, you specified none so I assumed you haven't)*

Easiest and most immediate one: pass it as an argument although this will require to modify the function signature:

```
// Start
recursive(par1,par2,par3, 0 /* Iteration number */);

int recursive(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int NbPositions, int iteration)
{ 
   if(iteration == 2)
     return something;
   else {
     ++iteration;
     return recursive(par1,par2,par3,iteration);
   }
}
```

or equivalently by decrementing the value till zero. This is also the most used way [prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) and other logic languages limit their recursion depth in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
int arecursive(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int NbPositions, int count)
{ 
  if (count == 0) {
    // ...
  {
  else 
    return recursive(NbProducts, NbPlates, NbPositions, count -1);
}

int recursive(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int NbPositions)
{ 
 arecursive(NbProducts, NbPlates, NbPositions, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can change the function signature, pass it as a parameter:

```
int recursive(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int NbPositions,int repeat) { 
    return (repeat == 1 ? result : recursive(NbProducts, NbPlates, NbPositions, repeat-1);
}
```

if you can't change the signature, then you will need a variable in the function scope to keep track of it. A member variable and a wrapper function.

```
int recursive(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int NbPositions) { 
    return (m_repeat == 1 ? result : recursive(NbProducts, NbPlates, NbPositions, m_repeat-1);
}

int recursive(int NbProducts, int NbPlates, int NbPositions,int repeat) { 
    m_repeat = repeat; // setting the member variable repeat before calling the function
    recursive(NbProducts, NbPlates, NbPositions);
    m_repeat = 0; // just in case
}
```